# Ascii codec error in passing data from MongoDB to Elasticsearch

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch

I am using dockerized MongoDB 3.4 to hold json data and I'd like to use dockerized Elasticsearch 5.6.5 to provide full text search on the dataset.

I was able to it mostly working by setting up mongo as a replica set and using mongo-connector (version 2.5.1).

However when I run mongo-connector it starts syncing the data with elasticsearch and then fails for a `UnicodeEncodeError`.

```
'ascii' codec can't encode character '\u01ce' in position 1397:
```

This blocks the sync and I end up with only a few entries of the DB actually synced.

How can I tell mongo-connector or elasticsearch to handle the strings as utf8?